# Auto height content in an iframe (CORS?)

Tags: iframe, height, cors

I am working with a client.  Their webpage is using this DOCTYPE

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

I need to deliver content to pages on their site.  My content looks like this

```
    <div style="height:1000px">
    <iframe frameborder="0" src="..." width="550" height="220"></iframe>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <iframe frameborder="0" src="..." width="550" height="220"></iframe>
    </div>
```

I can place the content on the clients page by giving them a couple of lines of css, and, currently, and iframe:

```
<style>
.iframecontent
{
    background-color:blue;
    position: relative;
height: 100%;
width: 100%
}
</style>

<iframe class="iframecontent" frameborder="0" src="..." width="100%" scrolling="no"> </iframe>
```

Because the height of the content is dynamic, I cannot provide a specific height to the client - instead I need it to stretch.

I've read many posts, but am still not sure of the best way to do this.  Possibly CORS?  Something else?

Here is one solution offered: http://sly777.github.com/Iframe-Height-Jquery-Plugin/ - it works on the same domain, but for cross-domain talk it relies on PostMessage which is an HTML 5 thing.

I've tried http://blog.johnmckerrell.com/2006/10/22/resizing-iframes-across-domains/ but have not be able to get it to work.

I might just get the client to set the frame to 1500px so that it should fit whatever I choose to be in the content and be done with it, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Could you just set the `html,body{height:100%;}` then your `iframe{height:100%}`?

A percentage height is directly dependant on it's parent's height (of a block element). ie: iframe is 100% of what? In this case, it's parent is the body.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the postMessage Plugin http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/

It enables you to post messages from inside an iframe to the parent element. In combination the the *setInterval* javascript function you may send the current needed size to the parent element.

**Inside the iframe**

```
var currentIframeSize = 0; 
window.setInterval(function() {
    var size = $('body').outerHeight(true);
    //just post, if the size has changed
    if ( currentIframeSize != size ){
        currentIframeSize = size;
        $.postMessage({if_height : size}, source_url, parent);
    }
}, 1000); //do that every second
```

**In the head section of  the parent element**

```
id = "theIdOfYourIframe";
$.receiveMessage(function(e){
    var rec_height = Number( e.data.replace( /.*if_height=(\d+)(?:&|$)/, '$1' ) );
    if ( !isNaN( rec_height ) && rec_height > 0 && rec_height !== current_height ) {  
        current_height = rec_height;
        $('#' + id).height(rec_height);
    }
});
```

Based on those two snippets, you should get your problem solved

Answer (score 0):

I updated my plugin that you tried (http://sly777.github.com/Iframe-Height-Jquery-Plugin/) and i added tutorial how to use this plugin for cross-domain fix. I hope it helps.